# Internal links in joomla 3.5 redirect to homepage

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have a joomla site which currently hosted on localhost. The problem with my site is, I have internal links that link to some articles, but whenever I open those links, I'm take directly to homepage where I have Slideshow CK image slider, but however the contents of my articles are showing up but I get the Image slider when that article opens, together with the slider which I have set it to appear on the homepage.

I tried searching on google, but no luck. I would really appreciate if I could be to resolve this problem with anyone's help as I'm behind schedule on launching the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

open a new menu and create menu item with your article which is going to be using as internal link.just save and refresh the page.

Comment: single-line solution/suggestion should be posted in comment.

Answer (score 0):

If your Slideshow CK slider also includes these same internal article links then make sure that your articles are also assigned to a menu link, or to a category and that there's a menu item for this category.

For example, if you have articles assigned to a 'news' category, make sure there is a matching menu link (Articles > Category > Blog or Articles > Category > List)

This menu link can be hidden if you don't want it to show in your main menu.

[Here's a Joomla documentation link](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item) which has an in-depth description of what may be happening.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was able to resolve by  installing an external module and disabling the slideshow using it.